# Custom class in laravel is not being recognized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I've been trying to create a custom class file for all my custom classes and append them in there, I'm using namespaces in order to accomplish using them in my controller however the controller is not recognizing the class

Ok:

Here is my custom class file placed in my project as `app/Library/robloxClasses.php`

```
namespace App\Library; 

class RobloxMaths{
    public function sortArrayOfArray(&$array, $subfield)
    {
            $sortarray = array();
            foreach ($array as $key => $row)
            {
                $sortarray[$key] = $row[$subfield];
            }

            array_multisort($sortarray, SORT_DESC, $array);
    }
}
```

`Library` is a folder i made to store all my custom class files in there

Here is how my controller `ApiController` uses the file using it's namespace

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Library\RobloxMaths;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ApiController extends Controller
{

protected $RobloxClass;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->$RobloxClass= new RobloxMaths;
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is, it keeps returning:

```
Class 'App\Library\RobloxMaths' not found
```

And I honestly do not know what's wrong, please help!

**NOTE:** I have tried composer update, and it fixes it temporarily but after a day or two or after me installing new dependencies it notifies me that the Class 'App\Library\RobloxMaths' not found thing happened

help please

Comment: Have you tried `composer dumpauto`?

Comment: @Baheeg - Please do `composer dump-autoload` once and then try....

Comment: I tried , still doesn't do anything

Comment: Your class name `RobloxMaths` does not match your filename `robloxClasses.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have correctly setup the psr-4 autoload root in your composer.json file and that your file/directory names match perfectly including capitalisation, *then* run `composer dump-autoload`.

Example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

This will assign the root namespace `App` to the `app` folder.

If you are using an IDE, there is a large chance that your `use` and `namespace` statements where auto-generated with the lowercase `app` to match the directory name. As all the names tie up correctly in the IDE there are no errors, but when it comes to running the PHP script the autoloader is not doing `require|require_once` on your files and therefore your classes are not available.

**Option 1 (Do this)**

Ensure that your namespaces have consistent capitalisation that matches the `composer.json` entry.

**Option 2 (Written for completion)**

Ensure that you add a new entry for this root namespace to your `composer.json` file. For the example above this would be:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "app\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but I had the same problem with laravel 9,
The problem is that I've used php short tag <? instead of <?php at the custom class file.

it's silly but this was the solution for me.

Comment: Holy shit. This took me HOURS of debugging... thanks for pointing that out.